# Changing displayed size

Tags: mesh

I have extruded a floorplan. To stay relatively close to the elements that I need to extrude, I have chosen a certain grid scale.

However, the model size is not what I intended.

I wanted to make the front wall like 6 metres.

Is there a relatively easy way to change the mesh size so that the front wall becomes like 6 metres while keeping the grid element size?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can change the *Scale* in *Properties > Scene > Units* (visible in your screenshot) to adjust the units without actually changing the geometry.

Comment: Where is "Properties" located at, please? I am having such a hard time finding things in Blender. I have found a "Scene" tab under "Grease Pencil", but I guess that is not what you meant.

Comment: The properties editor is the big vertical section on the right

Comment: Do you mean Scene->Units->Scale? That would change the grid size for me. I tried to avoid that.

Comment: Oh I see. Well never mind that then..

Answer (score 1):

After setting the scene scale in the Blender Properties panel so that the units report 6m, you can adjust the grid scale under the display properties, in the 3D view Panel (press <kbd>N</kbd> hovering over the 3D view), until you get the result you want.

[image: scene unites]
[image: properties panel grid floor settings]

Answer (score 0):

Any asset (object, mesh, texture etc) can be scaled independently of the world scale or grid size.

Here is a link to the official [blender manual pages for using the scale tools](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/scale.html)

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the scale of the *Units*, rather than the actual size of the object.